# Click-event does not always propagate to document.body on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mobile-devices

On mobile devices when you tap on an element, a click event is fired. However, it doesn't always travel up to `document.body`.

```
<body>
    <div class="with-click"></div>
</body>

document.querySelector('.with-click').addEventListener('click', (e) => ...);

document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => ...);
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/soo9b4mf/4/).

Now, when you click outside the `div` nothing happens on the `body` but when you click inside the div the body receives the click event. If you, for example, remove the click listener from that div ([DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/soo9b4mf/5/)) the click is no longer received.

Is this normal behaviour? and can this be fixed?

Comment: What mobile device? Because the first demo in your question works like it should on android. and the second as well. fyi in the fiddle the `body` is not the whole lower right frame.

Comment: Check, you're right, with your fix it works on android, but not on iOS devices

Comment: wasn't my fix and it works with your original fiddle. no fix needed. can't test on ios

Comment: sorry for that. I was indeed also clicking outside the body (didn't see that one) I've fixed that, but still not working ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/soo9b4mf/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Change `document.body.addEventListener` to just `document.addEventListener("click", ...)`.

I have verified that this solves the problem on iOS using **[this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soo9b4mf/14/)**.

Comment: Can you confirm that in your fiddle, if you click to the right of the red box it doesn't work? Checkout my updated demo in which I have given the body a height of 100% [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/soo9b4mf/16/)

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri No, it should report `body` when you click to the right of the red box because you manually decreased the width of the `div`, exposing the rest of that line as part of the document's body. Also, the `body` already has an implied `height` of  100%. Setting it only makes a difference when child elements have their `height` set to a percentage, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Hmm, I still cannot reproduce. When I click inside the body (not the red box) it doesn't work. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/soo9b4mf/23/). I've validated this on my iPhone 5 and simulator running iOS 10.3